# It is required to use Suspense, but I am not using lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my test file always ask me to use Suspense while I am not using lazy loading. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code

```
export function Filter() {
  const { accountingPeriod } = useInitTerm()
  const filters = reportSlice.useSlice(useShallow(state => state.filters))
  const setFilters = reportSlice.setFilters

  return (
    <StyledFilter>
      <StyledLabel>{t('output_target_accounting_period')}</StyledLabel>
      <AutoCompleteSelect
        name="term"
        allowClear={false}
        valueField="id"
        textField="text"
        value={filters?.currentTermId}
        items={accountingPeriod}
        onChange={(currentTermId: number) => setFilters(prevFilters => ({ ...prevFilters, currentTermId }), true)} // trigger query
      />
      <StyledLabel>{t('output_method')}</StyledLabel>
      <AutoCompleteSelect
        name="report_type"
        allowClear={false}
        value={filters?.reportType}
        valueField="type"
        textField="text"
        items={reportTypes}
        onChange={(reportType: number) => setFilters(prevFilters => ({ ...prevFilters, reportType }))}
      />
    </StyledFilter>
  )
}
```

And my test file

```
describe('<Filter />', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    render(<Filter />)
    expect(screen.getByText('output_target_accounting_period')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText('output_method')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

And i got an error

```
 Filter suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

 Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display
```

I expect no compulsion with Suspense

Comment: Please do NOT put the tag information back in the title. The tagging system here works very well, and does not need help. Repeating the tags in the title is just useless noise.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for reminding

Comment: When someone sees this that can help, they will. It doesn't speed things up by posting comments. This site works by people who volunteer their time to answer questions. There is no immediate response - sometimes it takes hours, days, or longer to get help. You'll need to be patient and wait. If you need help faster than that, you'll need to go to a site where you can hire someone to provide you fast help. While you're waiting, you may want to go back and take the [tour] and read the [help] pages again to better understand how the site works.